# Article signature figure?

Tags: article

What is the correct way to add a signature figure to an article in LaTeX?
I need to sign an article by adding the image of my signature under my typeset name.

This are the packages and the document class I'm using now:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[greek, italian]{babel}
\usepackage{fullpage}

\usepackage{boxedminipage}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{minitoc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
```

Now my name is aligned onto the right of the page by using:

```
\flushright\parbox{5cm}{Daniele Spinosa}
```

like a letter signature. I'd like to add my signature image below it.
How can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Mica essentially answered your question. To make it slightly more complete: Instead of

```
\flushright\parbox{5cm}{Daniele Spinosa}
```

(you don't need the `\parbox` here) use

```
\flushright
Daniele Spinosa
\includegraphics[width=2.5cm]{sig.jpg}
```

(You might want to adjust the `2.5cm`.)

Comment: `\flushrigth` is not a valid commad it's the internal start of the `{flushright}` environment. Better use `\raggedleft` or `\hspace*{\fill}Daniel`, if only a single line should be pushed to the right margin, instead ...

Answer (score 3):

First of all, if your signature is scanned as a bitmap file such as PNG or JPG, try to convert it to vector with [potrace](http://potrace.sourceforge.net/).  If you use Inkscape this is pretty straightforward.  Save it as PDF.  It will be much prettier.

Then you want to `\includegraphics` but set the bounding box to make the graphic reserve less space than its actual extent.  That produces an effect like you're writing on paper.

```
Yours TeXnically,

Microspino

\includegraphicics[bb=0 0 144 72]{sig.pdf}
```

To be honest I've never been good at hacking the bounding box, so if it were me I would use TikZ here:

```
Microspino

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \usesasboundingbox (0,0) rectangle (5cm,4em); % <--adjust the height if you want
  \node[anchor=south west] {\includegraphics{sig.pdf}};  
\end{tikzpicture}
```

If you want things on the right you can use `\flushright` as above.

Answer (score 1):

sign your name on a piece of paper, then scan it. Then use `\includegraphics{sig.jpg}`

Comment: I own already a scanned picture, I need to place the figure just under my typeset name.

Comment: Hendrik's answer above should do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

Once you have scanned your signature (e.g. `Signature.png`), I would suggest `flushright` environment.

```
\vspace{2cm}
\begin{flushright}
Daniele Spinosa \hspace{1.5cm}\null\\
\includegraphics[width=5.5cm]{Signature.png}
\end{flushright}
```

First change the `width` parameter so that the signature has the right dimension (the signature letters should have almost the same dimension of the text letters). Then adjust `\hspace` to center your name with your signature.