# Generating / Creating a signature in Latex

Tags: fonts

I am trying to include a signature on my cover letter in latex.

I would like to know if it is possible to create a signature in Latex. I am new to latex and I want to be able to create a signature with halohandletter font {Batman}. Can anyone show me how this can be done ?

I apologise I do not have a minimum working example.

Comment: the only to get the signature is by taking a screenshot ? How do I use `gimp` ? Can you give me an example please ?

Comment: Extremely quick option (if you are in a rush), in the following link, replace "BATMAN" by your name http://img.dafont.com/preview.php?text=BATMAN&ttf=halohandletter0&ext=1&size=45&psize=l&y=44, then save the image and include it in your document with `\includegraphics` (e.g. http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4882/1871). quote: This font is free for non-commercial use and donationware for commercial use. Other alternative fonts: http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/30-free-handwriting-fonts-every-designer-should-own

Comment: Actually you can grab the image from dafont: in Firefox right click on the image, "View background image", then save it as .bmp or whatever.

Comment: @FloDD, I found another workaround (that also allows to change the text in the link itself), see my updated comment.

Comment: @alfC, would you please convert your comment into an answer?

Comment: Just a comment: I really would not recommend using that font for a signature to be included in a cover letter if the letter concerns an application for a job, university place, internship... anything serious. The best way to include your signature is to sign a piece of paper and scan the result. (If you have access to a graphics tablet, you could use that instead.) A cover letter should be signed *by you* with *your usual signature*. If this isn't possible, just type your name - don't fake a signature, especially not in a comic font.

Answer (score 0):

(converted from a comment)

In the following link, replace "BATMAN" by your name:

http://img.dafont.com/preview.php?text=BATMAN&ttf=halohandletter0&ext=1&size=45&psize=l&y=44,

then save the image and include it in your document with

`\includegraphics` or as described in https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/4882/1871.

> This font is free for non-commercial use and donationware for
>   commercial use.

Other alternative fonts: http://blog.spoongraphics.co.uk/freebies/30-free-handwriting-fonts-every-designer-should-own